# Walk Forward Analysis Using Portfolio Analytics R

Tags: programming, portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization

I am learning how to use the Portfolio Analytics package in R and I am concerned with overfitting the data for the optimization.

The optimize.portfolio.rebalancing() function has 2 parameters that might help with this:

**training_period**
item{training_period}{an integer of the number of periods to use as 
a training data in the front of the returns data}

**rolling_window**
\item{rolling_window}{an integer of the width (i.e. the number of periods)
of the rolling window, the default of NULL will run the optimization 
using the data from inception.}

There is also some documentation with an example from CRAN. Here is the [Link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/PortfolioAnalytics.pdf) Pg.84

However, I am having a little difficulty understanding exactly what these do. In my script, I am rebalancing monthly and using daily data. I would like to do something like a Walk Forward Analysis - Optimize on 0:60 days and then test performance on 61:70 days.

Would my parameters be set to: 
rolling_window = 70; training_period = 60 ?